# Intercept Spring CAS Login for extra validation step

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, cas

I am trying to perform an extra step of validation Spring + CAS has been able to successfully authenticate credentials.

Within the system I am working on, not only are users considered active or inactive but there are also subscriptions to access application services. I am trying to detect users with no valid subscriptions and then fail authentication and send the user back to the login screen with a message explaining the nature of the error.

I am trying various means of achieving this. I am able to get all the information about subscriptions using and implementation of the Spring UserDetailsService. From there I can establish if a given user has active subscriptions.

The part I am having difficulty with is trying to fail the login flow in that case.

The UserDetailsService can throw a UsernameNotFoundException but I haven't found an elegant way of handling those within the application.

The approach I have tried the most is creating a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler. The thing is that by this point CAS has already authenticated the user. I have tried setting the setAuthenticated method of the Authentication object to false to try and invalidate the authentication. I have also tried redirecting to logout. With CAS being a centralised service, getting the correct redirect URL is proving to be a real pain.

I wondered if anyone who has more expertise with Spring Security might be able to suggest a better way of adding an extra validation step on login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the authentication is performed by your CAS server, why not creating a custom authentication handler in CAS which checks if the user has valid subscriptions in addition to validate the user credentials?

Comment: Would this be a subclass of the CAS authentication handler?

Comment: If you use CAS server v4, it should be a sublcass of: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/master/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/authentication/handler/support/AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler.java